# Feed the Beast Unhinged Version History

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My server is currently running FTB Unhinged version 1.0.1

I logged in today and noticed that for the first time ever FTB Unhinged is no longer a private code only pack, and it seems to be released to the public as version 1.1.0

What are the differences between these two packs?

Comment: [Slowpoke](https://twitter.com/slowpoke101) is still [busy updating the packs in the launcher](https://twitter.com/Slowpoke101/status/362266490554159105) and is promising a changelog soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: [None](https://twitter.com/FTB_Team/status/362111370843525122)

Long answer: [Unhinged moved to public release. No changes from 1.0.1](http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/changelog-for-ftb-unhinged-pack.26781/)